# My COUNTIFS statement doesn't seem to be returning the correct results

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to count how many accounts have been opened for less than 12 months. However, I do NOT want to count any accounts that have been labeled as "Closed". So I plugged in this COUNTIFS formula, but it is not returning the correct numbers for some reason and I am not sure why.

=COUNTIFS('Integrity Threats(IT)'!AE60:AE65536,"<=11",'Integrity Threats(IT)'!B60:B65536,"<>closed")

Comment: I just wanted someone to look at the formula and tell me if it looked roughly like what I was trying to accomplish. I'm apparently not getting the correct counts back from it though. This is a file for a client of mine, so I am partially suspecting that maybe the miscount is on THEIR end.

Comment: Are you sure you *know* what the "correct" numbers should be?
You could try it on a smaller example of the data where you can manually count the "correct" numbers and debug the formula that way.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks dead on to me too, but to verify you could try a sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Integrity Threats(IT)'!AE60:AE65536 <= 11), --('Integrity Threats(IT)'!B60:B65536<>"closed"))
```

Or you could straight up filter the rows and see how many you end up with.